# How does StackOverflow sanitize question titles for use in the URL

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, url-encoding

I'm interested in knowing how StackOverflow sanitizes the question titles for use in the URLs.

Are they using a custom matching and replacing pattern or something as simple as a `Server.UrlEncode` with some replacements?

Comment: They seem to halfway-preserve math syntax: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17477/why-displaystyle-i-hbar-frac-partial-partial-t-can-not-be-considered-as-t